# Is there enough XP to unlock every upgrade in Payday: The Heist?

Tags: payday-the-heist

I've been playing *Payday: The Heist*, which has three upgrade trees (assault, sharpshooter, support).

Each time you gain a level, you proceed one step further up one of the trees.  You can only ever be on one tree at any one time, though you can change which tree you're on instantly at any moment.

Right now I've been upgrading each tree equally.  However, I'm starting to wonder: is there enough XP in the game to allow me to fully upgrade every tree, or should I pick the one I like most and upgrade only that tree?

Comment: Stupid question in the meanwhile but how do you select wich tree to upgrade? Just click on it in upgrade?

Comment: @RafaelCelerier - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33263/5398

Comment: You should be focusing on getting specific upgrades that suit your play style anyway or you wont be getting good upgrades for your guns or any crew bonuses till quite late in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are currently 213 "levels" each level giving you the next upgrade in your currently selected leveling tree.

I'm pretty sure you can select which tree you're leveling by hitting tab + 1, 2, 3 or 4, depending on which tree you want to level up.