# In Payday: The Heist, how do you change which upgrade tree you're on?

Tags: payday-the-heist

In Payday: The Heist, there are three upgrade trees - assault, sharphshooter, and support.  **How do you change which tree you are on?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While in game, hold down <kbd>TAB</kbd>.  Then use the numbers <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd> to change which upgrade tree you're on.