# What do the three small bars behind someones Reputation tell me?

Tags: payday-the-heist

There are three small bars that show up in the lobby just behind a player's reputation - what do they mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bars correspond to the number of levels/upgrades the person has in the three upgrade trees. The bars are **Assault**, **Sharpshooter**, and **Support** from top to bottom.

For example, with the person you circled, you can see that that person (you, I presume) is about 2/3 of the way through the Assault tree, but only 1/5th of the way through Sharpshooter and barely begun leveling Support.

In contrast, the person beneath them (Landy), has barely any levels in Assault and Sharpshooter, but they're about halfway through Support.

It's basically an "at a glance" way to see how your companions have leveled and what skills/weapons they may have available to them. You should probably discuss what you have, regardless, so you know you have enough (or don't have too many of) Ammo/Doctor bags and the like.

Comment: Do you know how you level up each category? Does it increase by completing challenges, or is there some other factor?

Comment: @akaGrim I shall direct you to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/in-payday-the-heist-how-do-you-change-which-upgrade-tree-youre-on)! If you have further questions that have not been asked already, please feel free to [ask a new one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). :)